# Quartz.NET does not execute nor raise error for a job

Tags: jobs, quartz.net, execute, raise

Using Quartz.NET 3.0.6, a "malformed" job detail definition was passed to be scheduled, so the job was not executed and no error was raised.

Job Detail passed one param as bool (ignoreHeaderRow) instead of string (ignoreHeaderRow.ToString()), changing the param to string fixed the issue and the job got executed.

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ImportJob>()
.WithIdentity("Immediate" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToFileTime(), GROUP_NAME)
.UsingJobData("InfolinxSession", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session))
.UsingJobData("unprintable", unprintable.ToString())
.UsingJobData("ignoreHeaderRow", ignoreHeaderRow.ToString())
.Build();

QuartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(job);
```

Is there a way to catch this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz.NET does log all execution errors when job throws an exception. You can enable [logging](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/configuration-resource-usage-and-scheduler-factory.html#Logging) (liblog abstraction hooks to NLog, log4net, Serilog) and watch for logs and have alerts with modern log aggregation system.

Other option is to have a [scheduler listener](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/scheduler-listeners.html) attached to the scheduler listening for scheduler errors and then perfom some action on errors like Slack notification or whatever suits your needs.